# Extract size (numeric) from string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, string-parsing

I have column in a table with values stored as

```
HX CAP SCR GD5 1/2-13 X 3 3/4
HX CAP SCR GD8 1/2-13 X 4 1/4 
HX CAP SCR Grade 5 1/2-13 X 5 1/2
HX CAP SCR Grade 8 1/2-13 X 6 1/2
```

Now, I need to store these values to another table like

```
CATEGORY               SIZE
HX CAP SCR GD5         1/2-13 X 3 3/4
HX CAP SCR GD8         1/2-13 X 4 1/4
HX CAP SCR Grade 5     1/2-13 X 5 1/2
HX CAP SCR Grade 8     1/2-13 X 6 1/2
```

I need to separate the Category from the Size values.

```
This is what I have so far, but it is not working the GD5 and GR8 are part of the category column.

SELECT  CustDesc
        ,'??????' as Category
        ,SUBSTRING(CustDesc,PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', CustDesc),8000) as Size   
FROM [##CustParts]
```

Result from above query

```
CustDesc                    Category    Size
HX CAP SCR GD5 1/2-13 X 3   ??????          5 1/2-13 X 3
```

Plz let me know what is the query to do this....

Comment: Please provide a better example of what you mean.  What is an example of a row in the source table?  How do you want it stored in the second table?

Comment: it seem like it can be done in a script and just insert after the string is parsed.

Comment: Try using SUBSTRING () AND CHARINDEX() OR POSITION() functions and see how you go.

Comment: How do you know that 5 and 8 are part of the first string and not part of the size?

Comment: Also are all the sizes the exact same number of characters (10 it looks like)? Why aren't you storing these separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make up a rule that seems reasonable.  For example, it looks like the size starts right after the first space before " X".  We can get this use the (primitive) string functions in SQL Server:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(left(val, pos1 - spacebefore))) as product,
     substring(val, pos1 - spacebefore + 1, 1000) as size
from (select t.*, charindex(' ', reverse(left(val, pos1-1))) as spacebefore
      from (select t.*,
                   charindex(' X ', val) as pos1
            from (select 'abce 15/3 x 2' as val) t
           ) t
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

based upon your example it looks the number 1 is your reference to parse the value in each tuple.  research tsql's SQL CHARINDEX Command - Find Position of Text in a String

are there more values to be parsed?  Please provide a better cross-section of data to be parsed. - thx

Answer (score 0):

Hi if your string always contains the character '1/2',then this would work perfectly.

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl(col1 varchar(200))

INSERT INTO #tbl 
VALUES('HX CAP SCR GD5 1/2-13 X 3 3/4'),
('HX CAP SCR GD8 1/2-13 X 4 1/4'),
('HX CAP SCR Grade 5 1/2-13 X 5 1/2'),
('HX CAP SCR Grade 8 1/2-13 X 6 1/2')

select Left(col1,CHARINDEX('1/2',col1,1)-1),RIGHT(col1,len(col1)-(CHARINDEX('1/2',col1,1)-1)) from #tbl
```

Comment: The diameter varies. This would not work since this is just one item I pick from the 200k list.